# ORA-00904: "STAFFID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle

I already create a table `Audit`. When I try to insert table using this script:

```
sql = "Insert into "& myAudit &" (Date, Time, AuditCode , DetailsCode, CurData1, CurData2, CurData3, PrevData1, PrevData2 , PrevData3 , StaffID) values ('"& myTarikh &"','"& myMasa & "','" & myAuditCode & "', '" & myDetailsCode & "','"& myCurData1 &"','" & myCurData2 & "','" & myCurData3 & "','" & myPrevData1 & "','" & myPrevData2 & "','" & myPrevData3 & "', '" & myUserID &"')"
```

It diplays:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: "STAFFID": invalid identifier

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STOP**, use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)! Your current code is vulnerable for hackers and errors when using `'` in one of the fields. Use something like this:

```
string query = "insert into myAudit (date, time, auditcode, ...) values (?, ?, ?, ...)";

OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, connection);

command.Parameters.Add("?").Value = myTarikh;
command.Parameters.Add("?").Value = myMasa;
command.Parameters.Add("?").Value = myAuditCode;
```

Note the use of `?`, since ODBC doesn't support parameter names, so **the order of parameters matters**!

Second, the issue is in the `StaffID` field, that doesn't seem to exist in your audit table.

Comment: How about ASP classic,it use same Script?Because i try using that script on asp classic

Comment: You tagged it ASP.NET. That's a whole different story. Do you really need to use that? That technology was deprecated 10 years ago.

Comment: I just ask,by the way that script is work,thank alot